# IBM MobileFirst 7.0 Windows8 App connection issue after iFix

Tags: windows, ibm-mobilefirst

We recently implemented MobileFirst 7.0 IF201609291531 iFix and started experiencing a windows 8 app connection issue when a new runtime is created on the server and a windows8 app uploaded:

- The windows8 App is deployed on a device via App Center
- When the windows8 app attempts to connect, the server log records the message:

  FWLSE0332E: The application some_app for the environment windows8 does not exist on the server. Cannot register this client.
- I double checked that the app was in fact deployed on the server, I confirmed the version number, app id, and server details in the wlclient.properties file.  The same build process also deployed an Iphone and Android app, both of which works and connects correctly.
- I decided to change the windows8 application access to "Active, notifying" just as a test.  The console did not save the message, and when I looked at the log, it recorded:

  000000e5 com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction              E Result: newruntime: mobileFirstServer///XX.xx.X.xx: There is no deployed application with name 'some_app-windows8-2.0.25'
- I managed to set the application access for both the iPhone and Android apps without any problems.

This behaviour is only evident on any new runtimes created since the ifix was installed.  When I upload the windows8 app to a runtime that existed before the ifix it connects as expected.

I've tried this on multiple MobileFirst servers with the ifix loaded and the behaviour is consistent across all of them.

My build setup is as follows:

- The binaries are built using MobileFirst CLI (initially with IF201607241420, and then with IF201609291531) using Jenkins
- The binaries are then uploaded and deployed to the MobileFirst server using the worklight_build.xml ant script
- Server OS: RHEL 7.0
- MobileFirst configuration: standard Liberty profile
- DBMS:  MySQL

Has anyone experienced this before?  Could it be a database or permission issue?

Our sys admin is planning on removing the ifix on Monday, after which I'll run another test to see if it resolves the issue.  I'll post the result of the test here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a work-around for the issue.

It seems the issue occurs if a new runtime is deployed via the ant scripts, and the application is also deployed via ant scripts (no manual deployment was done).  When I manually deployed the application via the web console it resolved the issue.  This manual upload seems to only be required once, after that the app continued to connect as expected even with subsequent ant uploads.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear you are experiencing some kind of a regression with the latest iFix. I suggest then that you'll just open a PMR. This is not a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks, I'll log a PMR with IBM.  I posted it here in case someone else experienced a similar problem and had a work-around.  In the end I did manage to find a work-around so hopefully this will help someone else if they run into the same problem.